# Python catch int or str

Tags: python

I've written a program that generates a random number for the user to guess. I'm working on trying to catch all the possible errors. The only one I can't seem to figure out is this. At the beginning I ask the user to hit enter to continue to the game. The program catches if they type a string or even special characters and punctuation. The only thing I can't seem to prevent is if they they type a number, the program terminates. This is what I have. The issue is in the first while loop in the try block. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

```
from random import randint #imports randint from random class

cont = input('Press enter to continue')

while True:
    if cont != '':
        try:
            int(cont)
            str(cont)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Just hit enter')
            cont = input()
            continue
    elif cont == '':
        while True:

            randNum = randint(1, 100)
            print('Try guesssing a number between 1 and 100')
            num = input()

            while True:
                try:
                    int(num)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print('Please enter a number')
                    num = input()

                int(num)
            if num == randNum:
                print('Good job, ' + str(num) + ' is correct.')
            else:
            print('Sorry, the number was ' + str(randNum) + '.')

        print('Would you like to try again?')
        answer = input().lower()
        if answer == 'yes':
            continue
        elif answer == 'no':
            print('Thanks for playing')
            exit()
        else:
            while True:
                print('Please type yes or no')
                answer = input()
                if answer == 'yes':
                    break
                elif answer == 'no':
                    print('Thanks for playing.')
                    exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you enter a number is that the program tries to convert the number to an `int` (which works), and then to a `str` (which also works), after which it breaks. Instead, try the following:

```
from random import randint #imports randint from random class

cont = input('Press enter to continue')

while cont != '':
    cont = input('Press enter to continue')

while True:

    randNum = randint(1, 100)
    print('Try guesssing a number between 1 and 100')
    num = input()

    while True:
        try:
            int(num)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a number')
            num = input()

        num = int(num)
    if num == randNum:
        print('Good job, ' + str(num) + ' is correct.')
    else:
    print('Sorry, the number was ' + str(randNum) + '.')

print('Would you like to try again?')
answer = input().lower()
if answer == 'yes':
    continue
elif answer == 'no':
    print('Thanks for playing')
    exit()
else:
    while True:
        print('Please type yes or no')
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'yes':
            break
        elif answer == 'no':
            print('Thanks for playing.')
            exit()
```

Comment: I was trying to work on different ways to catch errors, but this works. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain why my way worked for catching everything but a number?

Comment: Yes, what happened is that when you inputted a number, nothing was raising an error, so it just went straight to the `break` and exited the program. `int(9)` and `str(9)` do not raise errors

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    if cont != '':
        try:
            int(cont)
            str(cont)
            break
```

What it does here is try and convert `cont` to an int, if it succeeds it tries to convert it to a string (which is virtually always possible). If that succeeds it breaks the while loop and ends the program. 
In any other scenario other than an int when it tries to parse it `int(cont)` it raises an error and you continue to your program.

Once he pressed enter cont starts. there is no reason for you to verify he didn't write something before entering the text.